# wcf service certificate

Tags: wcf, authentication, certificate

I am very confused about the certificate credentials in WCF. 
I have a service and want to hook up with message security.

When i add a new behavior, the serviceCredentials tag has 2 options.
1 - serviceCertificate and 2 - clientCertificate.

What I am interested to know is the meaning of these tags.  Does servicecertificate tell the client the certificate it is looking for or is it the clientcertificate that is looking for the right certificate and validates?

I want to use basicHttpBinding.

Thanks you so much for answering the questions.

Answer (score 0):

clientCertificate you use if you're writing a service that requires a duplex communication pattern, as normally with each request, the client will send its certificate to the service, so the service doesnt need a copy. however, this isnt the case in a duplex pattern as the service doesnt have a request in the normal manner... so it needs it in advance.

serviceCertificate is as you expect, the certificate used for your message encryption

The MSDN notes cover them well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731340 -- serviceCertificate

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731367 -- clientCertificate

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

serviceCertificate tag specifies the Certificate used by Server to identify itself and for transport security. When client sends a request, server certificate specified in the serverCertificate tag is also presented to the client so that client can trust the server and validate it.